# stripping filename from html source

Tags: bash, sed, grep

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(ytu==undefined){var ytu={q:'//img10-server.com/image/7777-88-78678678676876/robotunique-testfile.png',po:'6567567567',
```

I'm a bit new with bash/sed and other linux scripts, I'm trying to grep the file name "robotunique-testfile.png" from the above source, reliably without causing potential false positives.

I was thinking maybe greping `"/\.png\'\,po\:/"` which is unique enough in this example. How would I turn this grep into picking the filename `"robotunique-testfile.png"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following regex (https://regex101.com/r/4LPNS0/1):

```
(?<=\/)[^'\/]+(?=')
```

Explanation:

```
(?<=\/)                   Look behind for a slash
       [^'\/]+            Match anything but quote or slash 
              (?=')       Look ahead for a quote
```

Use this regex in grep as:

```
grep -Po "(?<=\/)[^'\/]+(?=')" InputFile.txt
```

You've mentioned the regex should perform "reliably without causing potential false positives." In that case you could replace `[^'\/]` with a more general class: `[A-Za-z0-9-.]`